# Which percentage of One for All can Midoriya manage without hurting himself by the time he awakes his black whip quirk?

Tags: my-hero-academia

So Midoriya can't use 100% of One for All because he hurts himself. But he's been improving the percentage of it he can use without hurting himself, first it was 5% IIRC, then he increased to 10% and he tries to keep improving.

Which percentage of One for All can Midoriya manage without hurting himself by the time he awakes his black whip quirk?

Comment: Side note:- how can it be 100% if he is comparing it to all might?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Midoriya was able to use 100 percent of his power even before awakening his black whips and without hurting himself.**

As I stated in my answer [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/50739/does-deku-midoriya-ever-use-his-power-without-breaking-his-bones/50740#50740),

> this was made possible by Eri's power so Mizuku's body remains unhurt while unleashing 100 percent of his power.

Also, even before this, [with the aid of Melissa](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/My_Hero_Academia:_Two_Heroes), he was also able to use 100 percent of his power via the Full Gauntlet, albeit he is limited to three smashes.

Without any aid, *the current limit for his One for All is 15%*, as stated [here](https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/One_For_All).

Comment: ok, but my question goes for how much he can use without external aids

Comment: @Pablo Which I have also answered...As I mentioned, the current limit is 15 percent without any external aid.

Comment: Oh, I didnt see it.